# XSL multiple sort

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting

I just created a XSL file that sorts my XML.
Now I want to add so I can sort just some of the nodes in the XML file.

Like sort cars that are older than 10 year in price category. In other languages I would use `IF` and `ELSE` but cant figure this out.

This is what  I have done so far:

XML file

```
<autoads>
    <ad>
        <type>1</type>
        <name>Honda</name>
        <model>XL 1000 V</model>
        <regyear>2001</regyear>
        <price>129900</price>
        <adtext>2001 Honda XL 1000 V, 8.900 km. hög vindruta. Pris 129.900kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020115</addate>
        <volume>1000</volume>
        <category></category>
    </ad>
    <ad>
        <type>2</type>
        <name>Nissan</name>
        <model>Almera 1.4S</model>
        <regyear>1997</regyear>
        <price>119000</price>
        <adtext>1997 Nissan Almera 1.4S, 5 dörrar, met, 70.000 km. el.spegel/fönster, galv. kaross, c.lås, startspärr, airbag, nedfällb. baks. ABS, ute temp. R/CD, alarm, d.fäste, v.säten, s/v-hj.  EU-godk. full service, servo. Pris 119.000 kr,-.  </adtext>
        <addate>20020118</addate>
        <volume>0</volume>
        <category>5 dörrar</category>
    </ad>
    </autoads>
```

And my XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:template match="/"> 

<html> 
<body>       

<xsl:apply-templates select="//ad">   
<xsl:sort select="regyear" />

</xsl:apply-templates>   
</body> 
</html> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="ad">


<tr>
<td>
<h3>
Märke : <br />
<xsl:value-of select="name" />
</h3>
</td>
<td>
<h4>
Modell : <br />
<xsl:value-of select="model" />
</h4>
</td>
<td>
<h5>
Årsmodell :<br />
<xsl:value-of select="regyear" />
</h5>
</td>
<td>
<h5>
Pris : 
<xsl:value-of select="price" /> 
</h5>
</td>
<td>
<p>
Information : <br />
<xsl:value-of select="adtext" /> 
</p>
</td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you show the desired output, we can better help you figure out how to transform to that. It's hard to understand exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the exact requirement is, but maybe something like this might help you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="cur-year" select="2011"/>

  <xsl:template match="/autoads">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[$cur-year - regyear > 10]">
        <xsl:sort select="regyear" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!-- copy template -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```